# Zelle Advice: Nonprofit donor sent over 1K through Zelle to the wrong person who won't refund it?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer

We know it is theft if money deposited by a bank to someone's account in error is kept with knowledge that it is not theirs. But what about Zelle? Someone donating over 1K to a nonprofit sent it to a wrong number, they know who that person is who accepted the funds, but can't get the person to return it. It's been several months. Zelle says it is received and irreversible. What's the most effective way to resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the police don't think it is a crime and you believe that the person should refund the money, you can take them to civil court.

Because of the low amount of money you will probably not be able to get a lawyer involved, and be limited to small claims court. The complexity is that you will have to determine where to file, and if you have to file someplace besides where you live the cost could be prohibitive. If they aren't local, they may decide the cost of fighting it is too much and just settle. Of course even if you win, they can still drag their feet in paying, which just adds to your costs.

Looking at the websites of banking institutions that use Zelle, it appears that they don't get involved if there is user error. The transactions don't have the same protections that credit cards, debit cards and checks have.

Comment: Thank you. You are right the amount is below 3K, and could possibly be managed by a volunteer lawyer writing letters, convincing the person not to incur greater legal costs and actions, but there isn't money to go through court. Maybe small claims? The nonprofit switched to cashapp instead of Zelle, and I think Zelle should inform users in advance of the process you describe above.

Comment: Zelle _does_ inform users upfront, annoyingly often, that all transactions are final, and that it is your responsibility to make sure you use the right recipient data. Start getting used to read all those pop-ups.